# angular 2 : ngfor complex object

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a problem with the display of a complex object in angular 2 with ngofr

```
jobs = [
    new Job('MacGronalds', [
        new Position("Sweeper"),
        new Position("burger flipper")
    ]),
    new Job('Starduck', [
        new Position("Sweeper"),
        new Position("burger flipper")
    ])
];
```

How can I iterate through my object like that ?

```
<li *ngFor="let job of jobs">
    {{ job.companyName }}
    <div *ngFor="let position of job">
        {{position.name}}
    </div>
</li>
```

thanks !

Comment: so, how is the class Job defined? what are the names of its members? Assuming that Job is made of name and positions, its pretty clear that you are not accessing the positions array of the job instance in the nested ngFor.

Comment: You've provided the generator of the data, with `new Position()`, but since we don't know what your Position constructor does, we don't know what the final data looks like, which is all that matters for your template iterator. Please add the final object structure.

Comment: This is the final object structure [{
    "companyName": "MacGronalds",
    "positions": [{
        "name": "Sweeper"
    }, {
        "name": "burger flipper"
    }]
}, {
    "companyName": "Starduck",
    "positions": [{
        "name": "Sweeper"
    }, {
        "name": "burger flipper"
    }]
}]

Comment: Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47076681/edit) and add it as a code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your models should be like the following.

```
    export class Job{
    constructor(
        public companyName : string,
        public positions: Position[]
   ) { }
}

  export class Position{
    constructor(
        public name: string
   ) { }
}
```

and you have a field that stores the jobs like `private jobs : Job[];`

then you can loop with the following

```
<li *ngFor="let job of jobs">
    {{ job.companyName }}
    <div *ngFor="let position of job.positions">
        {{position.name}}
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "Positions" are an array in a property on the Job called "positions", all you need to do is:

```
<div *ngFor="let position of job.positions">
```

Comment: this is such a small change that I felt an answer wasnt necessary. My comment is more than enough for OP to realize what to change I guess.

Comment: is there a reason to not make it an answer?